# Customising the legend with seaborn `displot`

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I created a density plot using `Seaborn` like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'1': np.random.normal(1, 1, 20),
                   '2': np.random.normal(3, 1, 20)})

df = df.melt()
g = sns.displot(df, x='value', hue='variable', kind='kde')
```

[image: kde.png]

Now, I would like to relocate the legend to the upper left. Normally I would do something like this:

```
plt.legend(loc='lower left', bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1))
```

However, it cannot find the axis labels and handles. I cannot get them manually either:

```
handles, labels = g.ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
```

Is there anyway I can get the handles and labels from the Seaborn FacetGrid to customize the legend?

Comment: New in the latest version: [`seaborn.move_legend()`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.move_legend.html#seaborn.move_legend)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exploiting the structure of the dataframe you got from [**`pandas.melt`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html), you can use:

```
g = sns.displot(df, x='value', hue='variable', kind='kde', legend = False)
plt.legend(df['variable'].unique(), loc='lower left', bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1))
```

[image]

However, pay attention to the fact that this solution work due to `df` structure and it is not a general solution for every situation.

---

**EDIT**

As suggested by mwaskom in the comment to the question, since version 0.11.2, you can use [**`seaborn.move_legend`**](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.move_legend.html#seaborn.move_legend). This approach is general and does not depend on the structure of the dataframe you use to plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'1': np.random.normal(1, 1, 20),
                   '2': np.random.normal(3, 1, 20)})

df = df.melt()
g = sns.displot(df, x='value', hue='variable', kind='kde')

plt.subplots_adjust(top = 0.8)
sns.move_legend(obj = g, loc = 'lower left', bbox_to_anchor = (0.15, 0.82), frameon = True)

plt.show()
```

[image]